# TIMESTAMP_FORMAT FOIBLES

Tags: timestamp, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I've been struggling with loading in a data file into snowflake with a date/time format like: `2019-02-25 12:03:31 PM`

Unfortunately the `TIMESTAMP_FORMAT = 'AUTO'` fails. I've tried a host of different `FILE FORMAT` options, but there isn't a lot of guidance in the Snowflake documentation.

```
ALTER FILE FORMAT "SLBG_POS"."PUBLIC".SILVERWARE_POS_FILE_TAB_41 
    SET COMPRESSION = 'AUTO' FIELD_DELIMITER = ',' RECORD_DELIMITER = '\n'
    SKIP_HEADER = 8 FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY = '\042' TRIM_SPACE = TRUE
    ERROR_ON_COLUMN_COUNT_MISMATCH = TRUE ESCAPE = 'NONE' 
    ESCAPE_UNENCLOSED_FIELD = '\134' DATE_FORMAT = 'AUTO' 
    TIMESTAMP_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-dd h:mm:SS a' NULL_IF = ('');
```

If there's a good reference on what the correct string for the `TIMESTAMP_FORMAT` would be, it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Rob.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there.  The format in the following query should work:

```
order.csv:
Order date,Item code,Quantity
2019-02-25 12:03:31 PM,XYZ123,45
2019-02-04 11:27:25 AM,PPP987,404

CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE T (ORDER_DATE TIMESTAMP, ITEM_CODE TEXT, QUANTITY NUMBER);
COPY INTO T FROM @my_stage/order.csv
FILE_FORMAT = (TYPE = CSV SKIP_HEADER = 1 TIMESTAMP_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH12:MI:SS AM');
```

For reference, formats are documented here:

- [Date and Time Formats](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/data-types-datetime.html#date-and-time-formats)
- [Supported Formats for AUTO Detection](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/date-time-input-output.html#supported-formats-for-auto-detection), but beware:
- [Date & Time Function Format Best Practices](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/date-time-input-output.html#date-time-function-format-best-practices)

Comment: That didn't seem to work... maybe I'm doing something else wrong.  Snowflake throws this at me...  
Timestamp '2019-02-04 11:27:25 AM' is not recognized File 'aaa_testload.csv', line 9, character 133 Row 1, column "TEST_LOAD"["DATEORDERED":18] If you would like to continue loading when an error is encountered, use other values such as 'SKIP_FILE' or 'CONTINUE' for the ON_ERROR option. For more information on loading options, please run 'info loading_data' in a SQL client.

Comment: Well, you have an impressive set of format parameters.  Normally, the CSV has to be _really_ non-standard for you to need all that.  Are you sure the CSV is well formed?  Several of your parameters I've never seen in actual use before.  Perhaps you can share a line from the file here?

Comment: The format works with COPY INTO if you use HH12 for hours.  My bad.  For some reason the TO_TIMESTAMP expression works with just HH...

Comment: Thanks so much!  I've struggled with this for hours.  I also feel a little bit embarrassed that I wasn't more responsive when you sent the answers.  So thank you again.  What format is the timestamp based off? Is there a reference guide you can point me to?  Best Regards, Rob.

Comment: I believe Snowflake has looked heavily towards Oracle when determining their Date&Time formats.  I've updated my answer above with doc references.

Answer (score 0):

Set your `TIMESTAMP_INPUT_FORMAT` session parameter before your other DDLs/DMLs

`ALTER SESSION SET TIMESTAMP_INPUT_FORMAT = 'mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi:ss pm';`

Comment: That will also work, unless you have multiple formats in multiple files...